# D2 Visa: Portugal Complexities

Tags: portugal

Since the virus is slowly coming down I am looking into the D2 Application. Over here in India they have started taking applications again I think.
The reqs seem to be complex a bit.

But these things have been mentioned -

Original PCC and the respective Portuguese translation to be apostilled by MEA, New Delhi.

I used to live in NL for 1 year and need to provide PCC from NL as well.  Police Certificate from NL is provided in both Dutch & English.

What would be the case for my PCC from NL, do I get them translated and apostilled by Indian MEA? Or do I need to get it apostilled by Dutch Embassy (I am not sure if they do that here)

D7 and D2 visas:
Proof of accommodation (own or rental agreement) has to be for a minimum period of 1 year;

Proof of subsistence to be produced by submitting a bank statement from Portugal with sufficient funds.

How would I get a Portuguese bank account without actually being in Portugal?

I have account in IND-NL and can have sufficient funds there.

(My NL Student Visa has expired earlier this year)

If all this is kind of complex, is it possible that I come to Portugal on a Tourist Visa (45-60 days) and then apply for D2 from there?

Comment: Are you CURRENTLY residing in NL? The SEF website says that the PCC should be from your country of nationality OR from the country you reside for more than a year. On apostilles, only the country that issued the document has authority to apostille them. So if it is a Dutch document, only the Netherlands has authority to apostille them

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza I am not living in NL right now, but I have lived there for 1.5 years as Student. The PCC comes with an apsotille but not sure how to get a translation and get apostile for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so let's break the requirements down in a few blocks

### Apostilles

Apostilles are an international "authenticity seal". There are VERY few documents that are valid outside of the country that issued them, for example, passports. All other documents need to be Apostilled to be recognized as legitimate. The authority to Apostille a document resides with the country that issued it. So Indian documents need to be Apostilled in India. Dutch documents are exempt from Apostille due to EU treaties.

### Translations

Translations should be performed by sworn translators that are recognized in the country in which the document will be *used*. In your case, your sworn translator must be sworn in Portugal. An alternative is to use a translator that is sworn in India and have the translation Apostilled to be recognized as an authentic document

I can't find anything in the [actual text of the law](https://dre.pt/web/guest/pesquisa/-/search/635814/details/normal?l=1) that says that documents in English are not accepted. The European website does mention that if the authorities cannot understand the contents of a multilingual document (i.e. your Dutch PCC) [they may ask for a certified translation](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/family/couple/getting-public-documents-accepted/index_pt.htm).

### D2 Visa specificities

This is an entrepreneur visa - you need to have a whole other host of documents including a business plan, proof of capital for investment - there is no minimum, but it needs to be compatible with your business, etc.

It helps if you already have a legal entity established in Portugal.

For the bank, you can contact a Portuguese bank and ask about their options for accounts for non-residents (that's a thing)

### Can you apply for the D2 visa in Portugal?

No. This process should be done in your country of residence.

Additional source of information in English [here](https://beportugal.com/visa-d2-portugal/)

Additionally, you can get in touch with [CNAI Lisbon](https://www.acm.gov.pt/-/cnai-lisboa), they're a non-profit that helps immigrants